# "Cowboy" as an adjective for an object?

Tags: meaning, phrases, adjectives

I forget what phrases it's used in, but I'm pretty sure I've heard cowboy used an adjective to describe **something someone made** (most likely something poorly shimmed together on the road, just good enough to work).

I am not talking about people called "cowboy" or "cowboy builders" (even non actual cowboys), or things referring to the cowboy aesthetic.

Can anyone recall any usages of the word this way, or provide a proper definition? I've searched the definition of cowboy on many sites, but they all only provide definitions for it as a noun and verb.